# MyBatis Generator include Views

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis, mybatis-generator

Is there a way to include views on MyBatis Generartor? I am using v1.3.7.

I already look on the MyBatis Generator official documentation but nothing was mentioned there.

https://mybatis.org/generator/

I have stumbled upon [hotrod](https://hotrod.sourceforge.io/11.02-mybatis-generator.html) but not sure what will be the impact on our existing framework.

For reference, I am using Postgres 10.10, Mybatis Generator 1.4.0. Below is my mybatis generator config and pom.

MyBatis Generator XML Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE generatorConfiguration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD MyBatis Generator Configuration 1.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-generator-config_1_0.dtd">
<generatorConfiguration>
    <context id="context1">
        <jdbcConnection
            connectionURL="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/test_database"
            driverClass="org.postgresql.Driver" password="MyPassword"
            userId="postgres" />
        <javaModelGenerator
            targetPackage="com.test.model"
            targetProject="src/main/gen" />
        <sqlMapGenerator
            targetPackage="com.test.xml"
            targetProject="src/main/gen" />
        <javaClientGenerator
            targetPackage="com.test.mapper"
            targetProject="src/main/gen" type="XMLMAPPER" />

        <table schema="schema1" tableName="%" delimitIdentifiers="true">
        </table>
    </context>
</generatorConfiguration>
```

POM Plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.7</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1204-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: I just tested and it worked fine. Please add minimum information to reproduce the issue. i.e. 1) create table/view statements 2) generator config 3) PostgreSQL version 4) driver version.

Comment: I have updated my question. Thanks for taking time to test. :)

Comment: I could reproduce the issue with that driver version (9.4-1204-jdbc4) which is super old. Please try again using the latest version `<version>42.2.8</version>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ave, It works now. Wish I could upvote you many times. :)